# Azure Search charFilter not allowing mapping to empty string

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are using a custom analyzer and using the charFilter to replace punctuation with the empty string. The documentation states that this is possible, but when we try to do it we get a bad request error.

```
    "charFilters":[
         {
            "name":"map_punctuation",
             "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.MappingCharFilter",
             "mappings":[ ",=>" ]
         }
]
```

However if we replace it with another character ie  "mappings":[ ",=>a" ] this works.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. It's a bug. We'll deploy a fix in the next few days. Let me know if you have any questions.

Update:
This bug has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. While I've got you, is there any way while using a custom analyzer to include in the chain of tokenfilters something that removes punctuations.?

Comment: You could use the pattern tokenizer to break on punctuation but your tokens will be split which may not be a desired behavior, token foo,bar becomes two tokens: foo and bar. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks. But our custom analyzer is using a keyword analyzer which needs to keep all terms. Any other ideas. We actually need to remove all punctuations and white space. As a best practice in azure search, how would you design this requirement that has to also include a keyword analyzer. Thanks

Comment: The best practice would be to use the char filter. Feel free to share your contact information with me jlembicz at microsoft. I'll email you when the fix is deployed.